# Can bot mention user in a private message?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Can bot mention user in a private message?
I have a code that works, but mentions only author. I need to mention user, but I don't figure it out, how to do it?

```
client.on('message', async (message, member, user) => {
    const paipal = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        .setTitle('title')
        .setDescription('USER MENTION')
        .addField('de', '', true)
        .addField('de', '', true)
        .addField('de', '', true)
        .addField("add", "add", true)
        .setImage("img")
        .setFooter("footer")


if (reaction.emoji.id === '738453002054008873') {
              setTimeout(() => {
                  user.send(paipal);
              }, 3000)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside description change to this `.setDescription(user.username)`.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Yes You Can In Any Message I Thing! Here Code :

```
client.on('message', async (message) => {
const paipal = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('title')
    .setDescription(`<@${message.author.id}>`)
    .addField('de', '', true)
    .addField('de', '', true)
    .addField('de', '', true)
    .addField("add", "add", true)
    .setImage("img")
    .setFooter("footer")
```

Edit: This Is A Message Event (message) This Is Not Giving Information About User & Member!